# Google Colab not responding

Tags: google-chrome, google-colaboratory

I have a Google Colab notebook which was working properly before but now it does not respond at all. When I execute a cell containing a simple python Hello World program, the cell starts to run but does not give any response. Even I cannot interrupt the execution.

When I open this notebook in an incognito tab, it works. I tried with clearing browser cache but it did not work.

My other notebooks work without any problem.

I am using Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by reinstalling the google chrome.

Comment: This should be a comment instead (and that would be one of the last things you want to do).